# how do I get my loading symbol to load sooner with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I have a loading gif that I have appearing on the screen when someone comes to my page. It looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dvLoading
    {
        background: url(../images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    }
</style>
```

and my javascript that shows this looks like this:

```
<script class="code" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
    });
</script>
```

However, it seems as though the page loads and then the loading gif briefly appears. Is there a better event other than .load that will do the job for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So perhaps your problem is that your script to hide the gif starts running before the image is actually loaded.

Rather than loading the image with css, you could load it dynamically on document load and set your fadeOut to fire on image load.

js:

```
var $img = $('<img>', {
               src: '../images/loader.gif',
                id: 'dvLoading'
              }).load(function() {
                 $(this).fadeOut(2000);
              });
```

UPDATE

forgot to attach your image.  of course this could be to any element you choose

```
$('body').append($img);
```

Comment: I took out my css and removed my empty div in my html. I then added your code but my loader isn't appearing any more. When I debugged in chrome and tried selecting img tags in my page, there weren't any. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For example, when I step over the code that appends the img to the body, I run this in the console: "$('body')" and I get empty brackets. Do you think I have to place this js in a particular place? I have other $(document).ready functions on the page too

Comment: yes, it should be wrapped a document.ready like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnewby/JRS96/3/)

Comment: forgot to hit save after adding the doc ready [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnewby/JRS96/3/)

Comment: cool, I'm getting really close. My loader is now getting pushed at the very bottom of the page. since I removed my css, is there a way I can add it to this new function? Sorry, still finding my js legs :)

Comment: wait, I got it. before I appended the img to the body I did this: $img.css({"position": "fixed", "left": "50%", "top": "50%", "margin": "-25px 0 0 -25px;"});

Comment: is the behavior closer to what you wanted?  you can leave your css in place but take the url('') out of the background.  i added it into [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnewby/JRS96/)

Comment: awesome!  while it's always best to keep your css in a separate css file, it's also helpful to know that if you are going to do dynamic css in a new element, you can add it to the jquery constructor [as shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnewby/JRS96/8/)

Comment: yes, I think it's loading a little faster now. I also went ahead and moved my css to the jquery constructor to make the code more readable. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to achieve this effect the way you are doing it. Because your styles and your javascript loads with the page, so by the time you display your loading animation everything is already loaded. The only way you can achieve your goal is to load empty html shell with your loading indicator and javascript that will request the rest of the html through async ($.ajax) request, this way you can show your loading indicator once async  request is issued to get html and hide it when async request is done.

Answer (score 1):

the event you are using is correct as load is called after all resources are loaded including images css etc.

To make gif appear, instantaneously, before other images load in the page, try and load the gif at the start of body. Also, you can host the gif in a CDN for faster availability.